# Convert 1bpp BMP image to 24bpp BMP image

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I am trying to convert 1bpp BMP image to 24bpp BMP image. My code is here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<fstream>
#include<unistd.h> 

using namespace std; 

FILE *fw = NULL;

void write_bmpHeader(int w, int h)
{   
    fw = fopen("Output_Img.bmp", "wb");
    
    int filesize = 54 + 3*w*h;
    
    unsigned char bmpfileheader[14] = {'B','M', 0,0,0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 54,0,0,0};
    unsigned char bmpinfoheader[40] = {40,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,0, 24,0};
    unsigned char bmppad[3] = {0,0,0}; 
    
    bmpfileheader[ 2] = (unsigned char)(filesize    );
    bmpfileheader[ 3] = (unsigned char)(filesize>> 8);
    bmpfileheader[ 4] = (unsigned char)(filesize>>16);
    bmpfileheader[ 5] = (unsigned char)(filesize>>24);
    
    bmpinfoheader[ 4] = (unsigned char)(       w    );
    bmpinfoheader[ 5] = (unsigned char)(       w>> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[ 6] = (unsigned char)(       w>>16);
    bmpinfoheader[ 7] = (unsigned char)(       w>>24);
    bmpinfoheader[ 8] = (unsigned char)(       h    );
    bmpinfoheader[ 9] = (unsigned char)(       h>> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[10] = (unsigned char)(       h>>16);
    bmpinfoheader[11] = (unsigned char)(       h>>24);
    
    fwrite(bmpfileheader,1,14,fw);
    fwrite(bmpinfoheader,1,40,fw);
}

///Read BMP Image
void Reading1BppBMP(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* fr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    
    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fr); 
    
    int width = *(int*)&info[18];
    int height = *(int*)&info[22];
    int bpp = *(int*)&info[28];
    
    write_bmpHeader(width,height);
  
    cout << "Width: " << width << endl;
    cout << "Height: " << height << endl; 
    cout << "bpp: " << bpp << endl; 

    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[width];

    unsigned char pix[3] ={0,0,0};

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), width, fr);
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {       
            for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            {
                int rgb = 0;
                
                int bitStatus = (data[j] >> k) & 1;
                if(bitStatus == 1)
                    rgb = 255;
                else
                    rgb = 0;
                
                pix[0] = rgb;
                pix[1] = rgb;
                pix[2] = rgb;
                
                fwrite(&pix, 3, 1, fw);
            }   
        }
    } 

    free(data);
    fclose(fr);
    fclose(fw);
}


int main ()
{
    Reading1BppBMP("Input_Img.bmp");
    return 0;
}
```

**Input image:**

[image: 1bpp]

**Output image:**

[image: output]

Can someone help me. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So is the *reading wrong* or is the *writing wrong*?

Comment: There might be row padding bytes. Looks like it from the diagonoal skew you're getting.

Comment: I recommend that you create a small test picture that contains a rectangle. Makes it easier to see when things go wrong.

Comment: In addition to @Macke: The reading of bits might be done in wrong direction. This could be checked by replacing `(data[j] >> k)` by `(data[j] >> (7 - k))`.

Comment: Found in [Wikipedia: BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format): _The pixel values are stored in each bit, with the first (left-most) pixel in the most-significant bit of the first byte._ So, the bytes have to be read from MSB to LSB in your case i.e. `(data[j] >> (7 - k))` should be correct.